# Accessing resource properties from fxml

Tags: internationalization, javafx-2, fxml

I know I can internationalize JavaFX application within fxml file by writing something like this 
`<Label id="versionLabel" text="%appVersion" />`.
But what if I want to use a concatenation of two resource items.
I have tried this
`<Label id="versionLabel" text="%appVersion.prefix%appVersion.number" />` but it does not work. How to do it correctly?

Comment: I think this might eventually be supported through an [Expression Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding), however, for JavaFX 2.2, there is no support for binding an expression to anything other than a single value (e.g. there is no string concatenation expression binding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible. (but I might be wrong)

You might want to file an enhancement request: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com

As a work-around you could set the text in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I set it through java code in the controller after fxml is loaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
<HBox spacing="0">
  <children>
    <Label id="versionLabel1" text="%appVersion.prefix" />
    <Label id="versionLabel2" text="%appVersion.number" />
  </children>
</HBox>
```